# Regular expression exact number and only positive

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a little problem to obtain a regular expresion which satisfy the fact that match the exact number base on a list and the number is positive, at the beginning I was working with the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var patt1=/\b(100|101)/g;

    var str="-101";
    document.write(str.match(patt1));
    document.write("<br/>");
    var str="101";
    document.write(str.match(patt1));

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

But I realized that in this case it will return 101 and -101 as valid. Then I tried

```
var var patt1=/[^-]\b(100|101)/g;
```

but the result was `null` for both cases, then

```
var patt1=/(^-)\b(100|101)/g;
```

but the result instead of being `null` and then `101` was the opposite `-101 null`.
I want the 101 and not the -101 any idea about how to do this.

Comment: Will the actual strings contain other characters as well or will the whole string be the number? The problem is that `\b` matches `-` as well.

Comment: so `abd 100` is invalid input, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You **can** use this `regex`

```
var patt1 = /^(100|101)$/;
```

It excepts only `100` or `101` as a valid input.

But for this simply test, I would use:

```
if (str === "100" || str === "101")
    // Do something.
```

Comment: @Niko. True... I copied his code, and didn't notice it. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks ppl this fit my needs, and I can't use the if gdoron that you suggest due to this list is dynamically generated.

Comment: @user1428872. No problem, don't forget to accept an answer, you can choose one of those you got or write one yourself and accept it.

Answer (score 0):

This will match a number in a string that has nothing, or a character other than `-` in front of it:

```
var patt1 = /(^|[^-\d])(100|101)\b/;
var str1 = "Does this string contain 100 somewhere?"
var str2 = "Does this string contain -100 somewhere?"

console.log(str1.match(patt1)); // Finds a match
console.log(str2.match(patt1)); // Doesn't
```

Comment: Don't you think this `regex` is overkill just to match 100 or 101?

Comment: @gdoron I'm guessing (hoping) it's an SSCCE.